# Lambda backed custom resource cf template returns 'CREATE_FAILED'

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

The below lambda function is to associate a SNS topic to the existing directories, followed by a custom resource to invoke the lambda func itself. I see that the lambda creation is successful with the 'Register_event_topic' also completing. However, the stack fails after a while mostly because the 'custom resource failed to stabilize in expected time'; How can I ensure that the stack does not error out?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
    #creating lambda function to register_event_topic
    Description: Lambda function to register event topic with existing directory ID
    Parameters:
      RoleName:
        Type: String
        Description: "IAM Role used for Lambda execution"
        Default: "arn:aws:iam::<<Accountnumber>>:role/LambdaExecutionRole"
      EnvVariable:
        Type: String
        Description: "The Environment variable set for the lambda func"
        Default: "ESdirsvcSNS"
    Resources:
      REGISTEREVENTTOPIC:
        Type: 'AWS::Lambda::Function'
        Properties:
          FunctionName: dirsvc_snstopic_lambda
          Handler: index.lambda_handler
          Runtime: python3.6
          Description: Lambda func code to assoc dirID with created SNS topic
          Code:
            ZipFile: |
              import boto3
              import os
              import logging
              dsclient = boto3.client('ds')
              def lambda_handler(event, context):
                response = dsclient.describe_directories()
                directoryList = []
                print(response)
                for directoryList in response['DirectoryDescriptions']:
                    listTopics = dsclient.describe_event_topics(
                      DirectoryId=directoryList['DirectoryId']
                    )
                    eventTopics = listTopics['EventTopics']
                    topiclength = len(eventTopics)
                    if topiclength == 0:
                      response = dsclient.register_event_topic(
                          DirectoryId=directoryList['DirectoryId'],
                          TopicName= (os.environ['MONITORING_TOPIC_NAME'])
                      )  
                    print(listTopics)
          Timeout: 60
          Environment:
            Variables:
              MONITORING_TOPIC_NAME: !Ref EnvVariable
          Role: !Ref RoleName

      InvokeLambda:
        Type: Custom::InvokeLambda
        Properties:
          ServiceToken: !GetAtt REGISTEREVENTTOPIC.Arn
          ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your lambda doesn't support custom resource life cycle

> In a Lambda backed custom resource, you implement your logic to
>   support creation, update and deletion of the resource. These
>   indications are sent from CloudFormation via the event and give you
>   information about the stack process.

In addition, you should also return your status back to CloudFormation

> CloudFormation expects to get a response from your Lambda function after you're done with your logic. It will not continue with the deployment process if it doesn’t get a response, or at least until a 1 hour(!) timeout is reached. It can cost you a lot of time and frustration.

You can read more [here](https://medium.com/@sch.bar/a-deep-dive-on-aws-cloudformation-custom-resources-8e04c6d155fd)

Answer (score 7):

Alas, writing a Custom Resource is not as simple as you'd initially think. Instead, special code must be added to **post the response back to a URL**.

You can see this in the sample Zip file provided on: [Walkthrough: Looking Up Amazon Machine Image IDs - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html)

From the [Custom Resources - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) documentation:

> The custom resource provider processes the AWS CloudFormation request and returns a response of `SUCCESS` or `FAILED` to the pre-signed URL. The custom resource provider provides the response in a JSON-formatted file and uploads it to the pre-signed S3 URL.

This is due to the asynchronous behaviour of CloudFormation. It doesn't simply call the Lambda function and then wait for a response. Rather, it triggers the Lambda function and the function must call back and trigger the next step in CloudFormation.

Comment: That little note about CFN being async was what was missing for me, I assumed it worked the same as CFN transform macros which require a correct synchronous response from the Lambda...thanks for the link!